# Custom HTML TextboxFor mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I wanted to write an custom strongly bound html helper class for textbox control which would display the contents as
**Textboxlabel ! * Textbox**

where "!" and "*" are special symbols to be included while rendering the textbox control.
so that in the view when i use it as

> @Html.DisplayTextboxfor(x=>x.CustomerName)

on the browser i can see the result as

**Customer ! * Textbox**

```
{
  public String CustomerName { get; set; }
  }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
Customer cus = new Customer(); 
cus.CustomerName = "steve"; 
return View(cus);
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model HtmlHelpersLEarning.Models.Customer 

    @Html.CustomDisplayTextFor(@Model) 

public static MvcHtmlString CustomDisplayTextFor<TModel, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Customer cus ) 
{
var builder = new TagBuilder("CustomTextBox"); 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: you need to write custom html helper see this:http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: also:http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/

Comment: thanks for the help, one more doubt can we have strongly bound html helper classes in mvc? While i browsed the internet everyone gave examples for helper to display image but the problem being its not strongly bound to the model.. so could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: what you mean by strongly typed..?

Comment: html helpers are generic helpers just pass model property to render some element  on the view that's it

Comment: by strongly typed i meant tightly bound to model.

Comment: model  
public class Customer
{public String CustomerName { get; set; }}
Controller
public ActionResult Index()
{Customer cus = new Customer();
cus.CustomerName = "steve";
return View(cus);}
Index.cshtml
@model HtmlHelpersLEarning.Models.Customer
@Html.CustomDisplayTextFor(@Model)
public static MvcHtmlString CustomDisplayTextFor<TModel, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Customer cus )
{var builder = new TagBuilder("CustomTextBox");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());}
The details to be presented as
Steve !* Textbox

Comment: so what is rendered in this case?